# Is there any way I can catch assertions in Swift?

Tags: exception, try-catch, assert, swift

It seems that Swift doesn't have C#/Java-like exceptions and uses assertions instead. However, the book says that in production environment, they instantly crash the app. Isn't there a way around it? What about unit tests, how can I test that a certain function asserts that it gets a correct input value?

Comment: Where does the book say, they'll crash in production? I read it, as they shouldn't used in production and crash your app in development.

Comment: It's suggested that assertions should only be used during the development process as they will terminate the app.

Wouldn't the idea to be to use optionals in this case (where the optional either contains a value or nil showing the value is missing) and then go on to use standard defensive programming should the value exist?

Comment: In Swift, assertions seem to be ignored for "release" builds (compiling with e.g. `swift -O`). So unfortunately it does not seem to be the case that they instantly crash the app in production environment.

Comment: You can add try-catch support for Swift by following the instructions in this article: https://medium.com/@_willfalcon/adding-try-catch-to-swift-71ab27bcb5b8

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From Apple books, The Swift Programming Language it's seems erros should be handle using enum.

Here is an example from the book.

```
enum ServerResponse {
    case Result(String, String)
    case Error(String)
}

let success = ServerResponse.Result("6:00 am", "8:09 pm")
let failure = ServerResponse.Error("Out of cheese.")

switch success {
case let .Result(sunrise, sunset):
    let serverResponse = "Sunrise is at \(sunrise) and sunset is at \(sunset)."
case let .Error(error):
    let serverResponse = "Failure...  \(error)"
}
```

From: Apple Inc. “The Swift Programming Language.” iBooks. https://itun.es/br/jEUH0.l

For unexpected erros you should use NSException as point out by [lfalin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24017180/1107651)

Comment: Nowhere does it say that this is a good way to handle errors. It looks more like a contrived example for using enums.

Answer (score 4):

As you mentioned, assertions will crash your app in debug or production. They aren't designed to function like Java/C# exceptions. Their only real purpose is:

> Use an assertion whenever a condition has the potential to be false,
>   but must definitely be true in order for your code to continue
>   execution.
>   ... in situations where invalid conditions are possible, an assertion
>   is an effective way to ensure that such conditions are highlighted and
>   noticed during development, before your app is published.

Since you can use Cocoa classes in Swift, you're still able to use `NSException` for exceptional things that your code *can* handle.

Comment: Do you have an example of how you would do this in Swift? Eg how would I throw/catch an `NSException` in a Swift program?

Comment: @BradDwyer exceptions do a lot more than return a simple value. They allow the exception to be handled higher up the call stack, as well as provide catching only specific types (ie: more specific errors) and also using 'finally' clauses. Simply returning an error object (ie: NSException) seems like a huge step backwards in time. Perhaps this didn't make the v1.0 Swift spec, but it seems overly simplistic to not have an error/exception mechanism at all.

Comment: @Marchy Exceptions were "deprecated" even in Obj-C. Everybody is supposed to use `NSError *` return paramaters. The problem with exceptions is that they sometimes break that nice MRC/ARC memory model because `release` is not called for some objects. That means that throwing and catching exceptions leads to leaks.

Comment: @Sulthan Why do you think NSException is being deprecated? It's still listed as active in the prerelease docs for both ObjC and Swift language docs. The problem with NSException has been what the problem is with exceptions in every language. Programmers use them to report expected errors or as really inefficient flow control. They're meant to be used for exceptional circumstances that the programmer didn't anticipate. NSError is supposed to be used for error conditions that the programmer does expect.

Comment: I wrote a quick wrapper that enables try-catch for Swift. Check it out here. https://medium.com/swift-programming/adding-try-catch-to-swift-71ab27bcb5b8

Answer (score 1):

You can add try-catch support for Swift by following the instructions in this article: https://medium.com/@_willfalcon/adding-try-catch-to-swift-71ab27bcb5b8

Basically, it's a wrapper around Obj-C try-catch